# Probability of cycle in random graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory

I create a random directed graph, with N vertices and N edges, in the following process:

A. Each vertex has a single outgoing edge.

B. The target of that edge is selected at random from all N vertices (self loops are possible).

What is the probability that a certain edge, selected at random, will be a part of a directed cycle?

---

FYI: This problem comes from the following model of land trade: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/community/land-random . The meaning of an edge "being a part of a cycle" is that the relevant land-plot will not be returned to its original owner. My simulations show that this probability is quite low - about 3.9% in average. I would like to understand why, so I am looking for a theoretic solution.

Comment: What did you have for $N$ in your simulation? About $1700$?

Comment: I assume a self loop counts as a directed cycle.

Comment: N was 1000. A self loop counts as a directed cycle.

Comment: BTW, I see there are many questions about random graphs, why not add a "random-graph" tag?

Comment: For $N=1000$, the probability is closer to 3.9%

Comment: I checked again and you are right - the 3% I reported were calculated when only 99% of the vertices have an outgoing edge. It seems this has a substantial effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select a starting vertex and follow the edges, choosing the endpoint of each point randomly as you go along. Sooner or later you will end at a vertex you have been at before. If that vertex is the starting vertex, then your initial edge was part of a cycle, otherwise it wasn't.

Using this procedure, let's derive the probability that the initial edge was part of a cycle containing $N-a$ vertices for $0\le a< N$ (I'm parameterizing by the number of vertices *not* in the cycle, which happens to make the following formulas come out nicer). For this to happen, we first have to select a yet *unused* vertex $N-a-1$ times, which happens with probability
$$ \frac{N-1}{N} \frac{N-2}{N}\cdots \frac{a+1}{N} = \frac{(N-1)!}{a! N^{N-a-1}}$$
-- and *then* we have to select the initial vertex, for an additional factor of $\frac 1N$.

Summing over all cycle lengths, the probability for the initial edge to be part of *any* cycle is
$$P_N = \sum_{a=0}^{N-1} \frac{(N-1)!}{a!N^{N-a}} = \frac{(N-1)!}{N^N} \sum_{a=0}^{N-1} \frac{N^a}{a!}$$

Recognizing the sum in the final expression as a partial sum of the series for $e^N$, and using Stirling's approximation for the factorial, we can bound this probability from above as
$$P_N < \frac{(N-1)!}{N^N} e^N = N!\frac{e^N}{N^{N+1}} \approx \sqrt{2\pi N}\frac{N^N}{e^N}\frac{e^N}{N^{N+1}} = \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{N}} $$
but this is at least a factor of $2$ too high, because the exponential series was cut off right at its largest term (and the terms of the full series fall off slower after the apex than they increases to begin with).

**Edit:** I am [now informed](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/136996/14366) that $\sum_{n=0}^{k} \frac{k^n}{n!} \sim \frac{e^k}{2}$, which allows us to refine the estimate to an actual approximation:
$$ P_N \approx \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2N}} - \frac{1}{N}$$

Comment: That is probably *the answer* and certainly looks $O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\right)$.  [OEIS A001865](http://oeis.org/A001865) does not give a closed formula.

Comment: Fantastic! How can I quote your answer in a paper?

Comment: Empirically I suspect that something like $P_N \approx \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2N}} - \frac{1}{3N}$ may be closer

Comment: What happens if every vertex has an outgoing edge with a probability of q<1 (instead of 1 as in the original problem)? In this case, we get additional q factor in each edge, so $$P_N = \sum_{a=0}^{N-1} \frac{(N-1)!}{a!N^{N-a}} = \frac{(N-1)!q^N}{N^N} \sum_{a=0}^{N-1} \frac{N^a}{a!q^a}$$. How can this be approximated?

Comment: @Henry: Yes, possibly. The $\sum \sim \frac{e^k}{2}$ approximation may hide things of smaller order, so I probably shouldn't have included that last $\frac1N$ term anyway.

Comment: @Erel: I don't think you can cite an MSE answer for truth in a paper, so you will have to reproduce the argument there and credit MSE informally in a footnote or acknowledgments section. As for the $q$ version, I have no good ideas. What I could think of on short notice was too crude to even give a better upper bound than the $q=1$ limit.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also be solved using recursion. First we see that, the edge selected randomly to be a part of a cycle iff the starting point of the edge is  a part of a cycle

Let $p_n$ be the probability that the starting point of the edge is a part of some cycle
hence we can say that,

$p_n = \frac{1}{n}(1) + \frac{n-1}{n}p_{n-2}  $

This can be solved easily to get the closed form expression of $p_n$