# Approximations for the partial sums of exponential series

Tags: real-analysis, approximation

Though the question here ([Partial sums of exponential series - Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136996/partial-sums-of-exponential-series)) is similar, it is more specialized and I rather need a general approximation for an arbitrary partial sum.

Essentially, I am trying to approximate the probability mass function of a particular random variable and I ended up with a Poisson random variable's CDF in the mix. Hence, for my purpose, I need to figure out a reasonable approximation of the sum:

$\displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{r} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$ OR the tail, i.e. $\displaystyle\sum_{k = r}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$

Does someone know some approximations for this? Also, if there exist conditions for those approximations to be valid, I'd like to know them as well.

Thanks in advance!

**Addendum:** There appears to be a closed form expression for such a partial sum:

$\displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{r} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} = e^\lambda \frac{\Gamma(r + 1, \lambda)}{\Gamma(r + 1)}$,

where $\Gamma(a, x)$ is defined as: $\displaystyle \Gamma(a, x) = \int_x^\infty t^{a - 1} e^{-t} \,dt$ and $\displaystyle \Gamma(a) = \Gamma(a, 0)$.

Is there a simple closed form approximation for the Gamma function? At the end of the day, somehow or the other, I either end up with a summation sign or an integral. I just want to be able to pin down this partial sum as a numeric quantity, that is reasonably approximate.

Comment: What language/environment are you using for computations? Chances are someone has already implemented the Gamma function more efficiently and better than you could in a few hours. Unless the approximation is central to the research you're attempting to perform, use a library. For instance, in C++: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/sf_gamma/igamma.html

Comment: The idea is to not use exact values but come up with approximations that are suitable for analytical interpretation. I am attempting to mathematically model a system that has been implemented in real life. In order for the model to be of value, I need to make it as simple as possible. Therefore, to reduce complexity, I am using the mean values rather than the whole PMF, justified by ideas such as mean dynamics to model the dynamics of the system.

To be clear, I am asking for an analytical approximation of aforementioned partial sum. Thanks for the response however (May help me in the future)

Comment: Gotcha, I misinterpreted your phrase 'numeric quantity'.

Comment: How large are your $r$ and $\lambda$ ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use Taylor's series with remainder. We know that
$$ e^\lambda = \sum_{k=0}^r \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} + \frac{e^{c\lambda}\lambda^{r+1}}{(r+1)!}, $$
for some $c \in [0,1]$. Therefore
$$ \frac{\lambda^{r+1}}{(r+1)!} \leq e^\lambda - \sum_{k=0}^r \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \leq e^\lambda \frac{\lambda^{r+1}}{(r+1)!}. $$
You can also get these estimates using more elementary means:
$$
\sum_{k=r+1}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} = \frac{\lambda^{r+1}}{(r+1)!} \left[ 1 + \frac{\lambda}{r+2} + \frac{\lambda^2}{(r+2)(r+3)} + \cdots \right] < \frac{\lambda^{r+1}}{(r+1)!} \sum_{t=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^t}{t!} = \frac{\lambda^{r+1}}{(r+1)!} e^\lambda.
$$
We can get a different upper bound by comparison to a geometric series, when $\lambda < r+2$:
$$
\sum_{k=r+1}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \leq \frac{\lambda^{r+1}}{(r+1)!} \sum_{t=0}^\infty \left(\frac{\lambda}{r+2}\right)^t = \frac{\lambda^{r+1}}{(r+1)!} \frac{r+2}{r+2-\lambda}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for giving me an approximation AND a starting point to think in the right direction. Hopefully this approximation in itself is good enough for my purposes. At least, now I know which direction to look for answers. Thanks again!

Comment: Edit: The upper bound didn't seem to be all that tight! Lower bound was better, but still needed tweaking. I then realized I could use the quantity $c$ in $\displaystyle e^{c\lambda}$ as a parameter that can be used for fitting the analytically computed mean value (obtained from the accurate PMF). It seems to work perfectly for a well chosen, small value of $c$. I am quite glad that now, my analysis seems systematic and not ad-hoc as it was earlier! Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: How do you get the reminder of the exponential Taylor series approximation? You write
$$e^{c\lambda} \frac{ \lambda^{r+1} }{(r+1)!}$$
which can be no other than the reminder term. How do you get to that?

Comment: thanks for the answer! Is there any meaningful way to pick c as a function of r? That is, can one justify for example the choice c=1/sqrt(r)? Otherwise the bound becomes very lose. Thanks :)

Comment: Taylor's theorem only guarantees the existence of *some* $c$. If you want more accuracy, take more terms in the series.

Comment: I see, thanks for your quick answer. Taylors theorem is very general so I was hoping that maybe something more specific was known for this particular series..

Answer (score 1):

matlab has a built-in function gammainc($\lambda, a$, 'upper') = ${\Gamma(a, \lambda)\over \Gamma(\lambda)}$.

Also see "A computational procedure for incomplete Gamma functions" by Walter Gautschi.