# In the limit of $N \rightarrow \infty$, find solution $z$ to $\text{e}^{-(z+N)} \sum \limits_{k=0}^{N} \frac{(z+N)^k}{k!}=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: probability-distributions, asymptotics, roots, exponential-distribution

Fix an integer $N$, and consider the unique positive solution $z$ to the following equation:

$$\text{e}^{-(z+N)}  \sum \limits_{k=0}^{N} \frac{(z+N)^k}{k!}=\frac{1}{2}$$

For $N = 0$, we find that $z = \ln(2) \approx 0.6931$.  For $N=10$, the solution is $z \approx 0.6685$.  It appears that as $N$ approaches infinity, $z$ is approaching a constant value (maybe $2/3$?).  What constant is this approaching?

### Motivation

This is an equation I derived to find the median (or rather, the difference between the mean and median) of a generalized exponential distribution.  The case $N=0$ corresponds to the usual exponential distribution, or finding the inter-arrival times $\Delta t = t_1 - t_0$.  Higher values of $N$ represent the elapsed time $t_{N+1} - t_0$.

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297553) question.

Comment: @Lucian Definitely related.  Is there some kind of continuity argument to show that $z=0$ is the limit?  Because I'm having trouble seeing why $z$ couldn't take on other values, especially when $N$ blows up.

Comment: There are two routes I see. First we could use the Laplace method with the formula $$e^{-x} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{x^k}{k!} = \frac{1}{n!} \int_x^\infty e^{-t} t^n\,dt$$ (after setting $x = z+n$). As mentioned by Lucian the leading order will be $1/2$, so it will take some work to calculate the higher-order terms in the asymptotic (which will hold the information about the desired solution). Or we could use some other known asymptotic formulas which are more complicated and whose derivation is too technical to describe in an answer, but which can be manipulated to give the desired result.

Comment: (...) If you're interested in the latter method then I'd be happy to write an answer for it. In any case, your guess that the solution tends to $2/3$ is indeed correct.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: As far as I am able to see, letting *z* be constant $($say, $1\le z\le10),$ and assigning to *N* a large value, which increases with *z* $($such as $z\cdot10^3),$  yields a numerical result very close to $\dfrac12$

Comment: @Lucian right, as I mentioned the leading order is indeed $1/2$. The idea is that we can calculate the asymptotic $$e^{-(z+N)}  \sum \limits_{k=0}^{N} \frac{(z+N)^k}{k!} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2-3z}{3\sqrt{2\pi n}} + o(n^{-1/2}) \qquad \text{as } n \to \infty,$$ where the error $o(n^{-1/2})$ holds uniformly with respect to $z$ for $z$ in compact subsets of $\mathbb C$. So the bounded solutions to the equation $$e^{-(z+N)}  \sum \limits_{k=0}^{N} \frac{(z+N)^k}{k!} = \frac{1}{2}$$ satisfy $$0 = \frac{2-3z}{3\sqrt{2\pi n}} + o(n^{-1/2}),$$ from which it follows that $z = 2/3 + o(1)$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I'd consider accepting an answer like that, if you want to expand your comment into a slightly more detailed answer.

Comment: @Lucian, Ryan, I just posted an answer to expand on the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we let

$$
p_n(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{z^k}{k!},
$$

then the limit linked by Lucian in the comments can be written as

$$
\frac{p_n(n)}{\exp(n)} = \frac{1}{2} + o(1) \qquad \text{as } n \to \infty, \tag{1}
$$

and as [Aryabhata notes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/137001/5531) this can be found in Donald J. Newman's book *A Problem Seminar*. This limit is a special case of the following, due to Donald J. Newman and Theodore J. Rivlin${}^1$:

$$\DeclareMathOperator{erfc}{erfc}
\frac{p_n(n+w\sqrt{n})}{\exp(n+w\sqrt{n})} = \frac{1}{2}\erfc\!\left(\frac{w}{\sqrt{2}}\right) + o(1) \qquad \text{as } n \to \infty, \tag{2}
$$

where $\erfc$ is the [complementary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) and the error term $o(1)$ is uniform with respect to $w$ for $w$ in compact subsets of $\mathbb C$. Indeed, since $\erfc(0) = 1$, limit $(1)$ follows from limit $(2)$ by setting $w=0$.

Now, the expression in your question is obtained by setting $w = z/\sqrt{n}$, but the asymptotic

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{p_n(z+n)}{\exp(z+n)} &= \frac{1}{2}\erfc\!\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{2n}}\right) + o(1) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{z}{\sqrt{2\pi n}} + O(n^{-1}) + o(1) \qquad \text{as } n \to \infty, \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

where in the second line we've used the Maclaurin series for $\erfc$, doesn't given us enough information to determine the $o(\sqrt{n})$ roots of your equation

$$
\frac{p_n(z+n)}{\exp(z+n)} = \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Indeed, after substituting this into $(3)$ we see that to first order they must satisfy

$$
\frac{z}{\sqrt{2\pi n}} = o(1) \qquad \text{as } n \to \infty,
$$

and we evidently need more information how this $o(1)$ error term balances with $1/\sqrt{n}$. In other words, we need more accurate information about the rate of convergence to the limit in $(2)$.

This information was obtained by Kriecherbauer et al.${}^2$ using a version of the Riemann-Hilbert method. After some massaging their Theorem 3.3 gives us the asymptotic

$$
\frac{p_n(n\zeta)}{\exp(n\zeta)} = \frac{1}{2}\erfc\!\left(\sqrt{n\varphi(\zeta)}\right) + \frac{(n\zeta e^{-\zeta})^n}{n!} - \frac{\exp(-n\varphi(\zeta))}{3\sqrt{2\pi n}} + o(n^{-1/2}), \tag{4}
$$

where

$$
\varphi(\zeta) = \zeta - 1 - \log\zeta
$$

and the correct branch of $\sqrt{}$ must be chosen, which is valid in the limit $n \to \infty, \zeta \to 1$. One can check that this is a very good approximation even for small values of $n$. Here's a plot of the left-hand side of $(4)$ in blue versus the right-hand side in orange for $0 < \zeta < 2$ and $n=2$:

[image]

Substituting $\zeta = 1+z/n$ then expanding everything in series and collecting like terms yields

$$
\frac{p_n(z+n)}{\exp(z+n)} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2-3z}{3\sqrt{2\pi n}} + o(n^{-1/2}) \qquad \text{as } n \to \infty, \tag{5}
$$

where the error holds uniformly for $z = o(\sqrt{n})$. Below is a plot of $e^{-z-n} p_n(z+n) - 1/2$ in blue versus $(2-3z)/3\sqrt{2\pi n}$ in orange for $0 < z < 1$ and $n=2$:

[image]

and for $n=100$:

[image]

It then follows that the $o(\sqrt{n})$ roots of the equation

$$
\frac{p_n(z+n)}{\exp(z+n)} = \frac{1}{2} 
$$

must satisfy

$$
0 = \frac{2-3z}{3\sqrt{2\pi n}} + o(n^{-1/2}) \qquad \text{as } n \to \infty,
$$

and solving for $z$ yields

> $$
> z = \frac{2}{3} + o(1) \qquad \text{as } n \to \infty.
> $$

It's worth noting that your equation has many complex roots which are $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$ and are picked up by limit $(2)$ above, and many which are $\Theta(n)$ which require a different asymptotic to detect.

---

1. D. J. Newman and T. J. Rivlin
   *The zeros of the partial sums of the exponential function*
   J. Approx. Theory **5** (1972), 405–412.
2. T. Kriecherbauer, A. B. J. Kuijlaars, K. D. T.-R. McLaughlin, and P. D. Miller
   *Locating the zeros of partial sums of $e^z$ with Riemann-Hilbert methods*
   Integrable Systems and Random Matrices, Contemp. Math., vol. 458, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 2008, pp. 183–195.
   [arXiv link](http://arxiv.org/abs/0709.1213)

Comment: Good lord, hadn't expected that one needs this heavy machinery to answer this question (+1)

Comment: @tired, definitely one can get the same asymptotic in $(5)$ using the Laplace method, but it can get a little tedious, plus I had been looking at this recently so it was fresh in my mind.

Answer (score 3):

Your equation [can be re-written](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.4.E10) in the form
$$
Q(N + 1,N + z) = \tfrac{1}{2},
$$
where $Q$ denotes the [normalised incomplete gamma function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2.E4). Consider the more general problem of finding the $z$-root of the equation
$$
Q(N + 1,N + z) = q
$$
for a given $0<q<1$ and positive integer $N$. It is shown in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1090/mcom/3391) that
\begin{align*}
z \sim 1 + \tau _0 (N + 1)^{1/2}  + \frac{{\tau _0^2  - 1}}{3} &+ \frac{{\tau _0^3  - 7\tau _0 }}{{36(N + 1)^{1/2} }} \\ &- \frac{{3\tau _0^4  + 7\tau _0^2  - 16}}{{810(N + 1)}} + \frac{{9\tau _0^5  + 256\tau _0^3  - 433\tau _0 }}{{38880(N + 1)^{3/2} }} +  \ldots 
\end{align*}
as $N\to+\infty$ provided $\log (q(1 - q)) = o(N)$. Here $\tau_0$ is the unique real root of the equation
$$
q = \tfrac{1}{2}\operatorname{erfc}(2^{ - 1/2} \tau _0 ),
$$
with $\operatorname{erfc}$ being the [complementary error function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.2.E2). The paper contains an algorithm to generate the coefficients of the asymptotic expansion. In the special case that $q=\frac{1}{2}$, $\tau_0$ is $0$ and therefore we have
$$
z \sim \frac{2}{3} + \frac{8}{{405(N + 1)}} + \frac{{184}}{{25515(N + 1)^2 }} + \frac{{2248}}{{3444525(N + 1)^3 }} +  \ldots 
$$
as $N\to+\infty$. This may be re-expanded in inverse powers of $N$ instead of $N+1$:
$$
z \sim \frac{2}{3} + \frac{8}{{405N}} - \frac{{64}}{{5103N^2 }} + \frac{{2944}}{{492075N^3 }} +  \ldots,
$$
as $N\to+\infty$.